# Is it possible to "reverse" the Dunnett post-hoc test: 1 treatment vs several controls?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, dunnett

I have 4 groups of patients who received Hepatitis B vaccines (based on different vaccination policies) a group too old to have received it. One of the policies was not properly implemented and the the corresponding patients have smaller antibody levels now, similar to the unvaccinated patients. 
I want to use ANOVA to compare all 5 groups and I want to use the Dunnett post-hoc test to compare the unfortunate group with all other groups. As far as I understand, the Dunnett test compares several treatment groups with 1 control group. Is there anything that prevents me from "reversing" this use-case?
Thanks?

Comment: Are you thinking of Dunnett, not Dunn?  Also note there are two Dunn post-hoc tests: Dunn 1961 and Dunn 1964.

Comment: Yes, Dunnett. Thanks for pointing it.

Comment: As I read [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunnett%27s_test), it seems that you can designate any one of your 5 groups as the 'control' group and use Dunnett's procedure to compare the other 4 groups to that 'control'. The difficulty is that, in the midst of doing these comparisons, you may wonder about differences among the 4 'non-control' groups--especially if the designation of 'control' is not truly meaningful. // Depending on the P-value of the overall ANOVA test, you may be able to use Bonferroni's criterion, meaningfully to compare all 10 pairs of groups at the 1% level.